# mulpicaton by addition

Tags: php

I read a wiki that says for multiplication the CPU adds!

From wiki:

```
Pass the only weight-1 wire through, output: 1 weight-1 wire
Pass the two weight-2 wires through, outputs: 2 weight-2 wires
Add a full adder for weight 4, outputs: 1 weight-4 wire, 1 weight-8 wire
Add a full adder for weight 8, and pass the remaining wire through, outputs: 2 weight-8 wires,     1 weight-16 wire
Add a full adder for weight 16, outputs: 1 weight-16 wire, 1 weight-32 wire
Pass the two weight-32 wires through, outputs: 2 weight-32 wires
Pass the only weight-64 wire through, output: 1 weight-64 wire
```

I not understand whole, but I think it keeps adding then if it not know how to add it pass and goes next addition. here full article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dadda_tree

I do lot research and I think it is slow. So instead of the CPU doing multiplication I want to do it myself.

I wrote this function:

```
function do_multiply($a, $b)
{
    while($b > 0) { 
        $a = $a + $a;
        $b = $b-1;
}
```

All I want to do is if I asked function to multiply 2 and 3, I want to add 2 to 2, three times, correct?

So I want to do this:

```
2+2+2
```

This is same as 2*3, correct?

When I run this it gives me 16.  Why do I get the wrong answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function do_multiply($a, $b)
```

{

```
$res = 0;
while($b > 0) { 
    $res += $a;
    $b = $b-1;
}
return $res;
```

}

Comment: minus one for giving a complete solution when op says it's homework.

Comment: @xxxkellyxxx: Do you understand what you did wrong?

Comment: @King yes i not return!!

Comment: @xxxkellyxxx: Not only you didn't return, but you also doubled $a on each iteration.

Answer (score 6):

> why it not work?

Assuming that that question relates to this code:

```
function do_multiply($a, $b)
{
    while($b > 0) { 
        $a = $a + $a;
        $b = $b-1;
}
```

...then there are three reasons I can immediately see:

1. You never return a value
2. If `$b` is negative, well, that function's going to take a **long** time to complete, and it's going to return the wrong answer (because you're subtracting `1` from `$b`; you need to handle the case where `$b` is *already* negative, probably with [`abs`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.abs.php) -- be sure to read up on the results of multiplying negative numbers).
3. You need to add `$a` *as it was when you entered the function*, rather than doubling it on every pass. Consider: Starting with `$a` = `3`, `$b` = `2`. On the first loop, you're setting `$a = $a + $a` and so it becomes `6`. But then on the second loop, you're adding `$a` to `$a` again (`6` + `6`), rather than adding `3` (`$a`'s *original* value) to `$a`.

Comment: And there is a missing bracket... but that might be just a typo.

Comment: @xxxkellyxxx: Be nice to the people who are trying to help you, otherwise it is the last time someone helped you. You want something from us, not vice versa.

Comment: +1 For considering the negative possibility.  Your program will explode violently if you don't account for that

Comment: @xxxkellyxxx: Uhm no. @TJ said that your code will not work if `$b` is a negative number which is worth to point out. And this is not kindergarden here where we point at someone and say "he started it first".

Comment: Who the heck upvoted the "`b` is not negative you are" comment?! What the....?! @xxxkellyxxx: I'm not seeing where I said anything about your code other than pointing out what parts of it wouldn't work, which is surely what you *asked* us to do? Sorry if anything I said came across the wrong way. The phrasing of #2, in particular, is meant to be *humourous*. It's **well worth** giving people the benefit of the doubt when they're trying to help you (or, indeed, even when they're not).

Answer (score 5):

Look at your Loop, you are incrementing $a incorrectly;

first iteration:
$a = 2 + 2 (so $a = 4)

second iteration

$a = 4 + 4 (so $a = 8)

third iteration

$a = 8 + 8

You need to declare a variable outside the loop and add to that instead.

$total = $total + $a

Comment: plus one for explaining how the flow of the original code is wrong, so that op can grow mentally and have a chance at becoming a programmer.

Answer (score 0):

let's say `$a` is 2 and `$b` is 3, like you suggested, then your code would run the while loop 3 times (a.k.a. iterations), and i assume this is what you expected.

however, during the while loop, you change the value of `$a` by use of the assignment operator. this creates problems for you, since the idea behind your function relies on `$a` keeping its original value. this is why you need to have a third "result"-container to store the temporary results during the iterations.